# In bash: How to find and delete directories containing a specific file, only if the file is older than X minutes

Tags: bash, find

In bash, how can I find and delete the directories that contain a specific file, only if the file is older than X minutes.

There is 
[this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/739037) which finds the directories that contain a specific file. However it is not clear how to add the condition that the file is older than X minutes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### **Edit**: simpler way:

```
find . -name 'foobar.dat' -mmin +3 -exec bash -c 'rm -vr "$(dirname "$1")"' bash {} \;
```

Which basically, is finding the matching files and then erasing their parent directory. The second "bash" string can be anything, it is just there to avoid putting the file name in "$0" (although this seems to work fine...)

#### Previous less elegant solution:

I would tackle the problem the other way:

- create a small script that does an `rm -r $(dirname $1)` (ie, remove the parent directory of the argument)
- find all such files, and call the script on them:

  ```
  find . -name 'foobar.dat' -mmin +3 -exec rmparent_script {} \;
  ```

Comment: Any idea why it wouldn't work as a oneliner with `dirname`? even with just an echo: `find . -name 'foobar.dat' -mmin +3 -exec echo \`dirname {}\` \; `

while the following seems fine: `find . -name 'foobar.dat' -mmin +3 -exec echo \`echo {}\` \; `

Comment: The shell evaluates the backticks before running `find`. That's a [useless use of `echo`](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#echo) anyway. Try simply `find . -name 'foobar.dat' -mmin +3 -exec dirname {} \;` instead.

Comment: The proper solution doesn't require an external script. Just `find . -name 'foobar.dat' -mmin +3 -execdir rm -r {} \;` (which also coincidentally removes the [quoting error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable)).

Comment: @tripleee `-execdir` set the CWD to the parent, but argument is still the file (actually, ./the_file, and not /path/to/the_file), so your solution only erases the file?

Comment: Thanks for catching that. So, `-execdir rm -r . \;` instead.

Comment: @tripleee Doesn't work either: `rm: refusing to remove '.' or '..' directory: skipping '.'` But thanks for the inspiration, I found a better way: see edited answer, and hoping I got the quotes right.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Typo

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski It's unfixable. You accept the risk or not.

Comment: One may want to avoid putting the file name in `"$0"` because `bash` (`sh`-like shells in general) use it to report errors. Example: `bash -c '/makes/no/sense' my-bash`. If there was some random argument instead of `my-bash` then the error message would be somewhat cryptic. On the other hand we can use it to make potential error messages quite clear: `… -exec bash -c '…' bash-in-find-A {} …`.